# ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute:

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

Hey guys im getting this error when i try to upload to the android market.  Ive read some othere articles and have found that it comes from the manifest file, but i havent been  able to locate it.  Anybody have any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="h6ttp://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gymessentials.android"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.6" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/gymessentials"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.gymessentials.android.WebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
        android:name="com.gymessentials.android.WebViewActivity2"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gymessentials.android.WebViewActivity3"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gymessentials.android.WebViewActivity4"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
        android:name="com.gymessentials.android.WebViewActivity5"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gymessentials.android.WebViewActivity6"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.gymessentials.android.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo in the URL to the android namespace - in the `manifest` element at the very top of your file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="h6ttp://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
```

Try taking out the "6".